# How to add push notifications to iOS app (cordova-plugin-firebasex)?

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-ios, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I am trying to add push notifications to iOS app but the notifications never arrive.
Things I've done so far are:

- Add .p8 key to firebase project.
- Add push notification to bundle ID.
- Add remote notifications to app capabilities.

The push notifications work fine on the android app. iOS and android use a common backend for sending notifications.
I can generate a token by calling getToken and I can also get the APNS token.

I can also see an error in the console `[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][__a_hex_address__] get output frames failed, state 8196`. Not sure if it is relevant.

Also when I open the project in XCode I don't see any entitlements file in 'Resources' directory

I am using Cordova version 10 and Cordova ios version 6.2.0.

Comment: You have called FirebasePlugin.grantPermission? (this is only needed on iOS)

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: @TheWhiteFang are you able to configure push notification? if yes can you provide steps then that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the WORKSPACE in Xcode and not the project. Also you have to make sure that cocoa pods have been setup and update as per the dev's doc.

Comment: I have opened the `.workspace` and not the `.project`. I have installed the cocoapods as without it the build will fail.